# Azure and SSL not working in Staging

Tags: silverlight, ssl, service, azure

I create local certificat with IIS, I add this certificat to Azure project.
When i debug in local (Https://127.0.0.1:444) my service work well.

But when i publish my project to Azure Staging (https://a7a9e6ab******.cloudapp.net/), my service don't work?

My web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="50" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="DefaultSecuredBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="50" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="nVentive.Umbrella.Services.UserNamePasswordValidator, nVentive.Umbrella.Services" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: `Error: Crystal ball not found.` In other words, what do you mean, "doesn't work"? How *exactly* does it differ from what you expected to happen? Any errors? Warnings? What do they say?

Comment: I haven't error, it's for this reason i ask help.

Comment: And on Windows Azure with https i can't use Fiddler, I notice that my user donesn't log

Answer (score 1):

Have you uploaded your service certificate to the Windows Azure hosted service? Your service does not work most probably because you didn't upload your certificate. Please check the following resources about how to use certificates with Windows Azure:

- [Overview of Certificates in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981935.aspx)
- [How to configure SSL endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff795779.aspx)
- [How to upload service certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404003.aspx)

Also, please note that if you use the service certificate in your code to make some checks, you have to skip any validation, as no validation will pass with self signed certificates.